# How do I get my one year old to stop grinding her teeth?

Tags: discipline, teeth

My daughter is thirteen months old and has four teeth on top and two on the bottom. She is constantly grinding them against each other, which is not only bad for her, but also makes a sound that makes my skin crawl.

I've tried grasping her firmly and saying NO very sternly, but she only giggles and keeps on. I also tried flicking her on the nose once, which made her cry for about 5 minutes before she started again.

Does anyone have any tricks or ideas??

Comment: How long has she been doing this? Has she tried other things (her fingers, for example)? Have you tried giving her something else to chew on (a pacifier, teething rings, etc.)?

Comment: @anongoodnurse Yes, I have tried giving her a variety of things for her to chew on, but she loses interest in them very quickly. The only thing that she'll keep in her mouth for a prolonged period of time is a bottle, but once it's empty, she doesn't want it anymore.

Comment: How long has this been going on? Does she have sleep bruxism as well? Any developmental delays of any kind?

Comment: @anongoodnurse it's been going on for a few weeks, and no she doesn't grind her teeth in her sleep. She's not quite walking yet, and she sometimes tries to bite people when she's tired, but she hasn't been doing that as often as she used to. I don't know if these are considered developmental problems. She's 13 months old.

Comment: What is "constant"? Literally all the time?

Comment: My best guess is that she's just enjoying the experience of having nice, hard little teeth in her mouth and that this will pass in time (she'll get bored with them as well.) I did find one medical book that stated daytime grinding of the first deciduous teeth (baby teeth) is common and not a clinical concern. They didn't have any tips on how to stop it.

Comment: @anongoodnurse thanks! It's good to know that it's not unusual or anything. I really do hope it's just a phase. I just can't stand the idea of her ruining her brand new teeth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I've had this one. I had a little boy, about the same age, in my daycare that was a big teeth grinder. It was very random. He would do it for a few days then nothing. Here is what I would suggest. Ignore it. Eventually he stopped doing it.

These aren't permanent teeth. They will fall out at some point and unless it becomes some sort of stress thing or her dentist says anything about it, there isn't much you can do to stop it. Your daughter is testing a new sensory ability. Like biting...it's new, it's different, she's exploring it. And best of all, it's normal (for now). Annoying, yes, but normal none the less.

I would definitely stop trying physical punishment as a way to prevent it. She isn't at an age where she understands what she is doing or the consequence you're implementing. You're either going to just freak her out or make it worse which won't help anyone.

Just remember to breath and step away if you find yourself getting overly agitated about it. This won't be the last thing she does that drives you crazy lol.

Best of luck.